# how to order a datatable according to parent child relation in the same table

Tags: sql, select, parent-child

I have table like below

```
ID |CODE      | Description
--------------------------
1  |A         | Parent Test
2  |A.1       | First Level Child
3  |A.2       | First Level Child 2
4  |A.1.1     | Second Level Child
```

I want to do a Select and get the table as below

```
ID |PARENT ID |CODE      | Description
---------------------------------------
1  | 0        |A         | Parent Test
2  | 1        |A.1       | First Level Child
3  | 1        |A.2       | First Level Child 2
4  | 2        |A.1.1     | Second Level Child
```

Is that possible to get the expected datatable from the top table with SQL SELECT statement? I dont want to do it in C#, therefore I have to do it in SQL

Comment: It's possible, but it would be easier if you replaced your code field with a parent_id field.

Comment: I know, but the database is designed this way and I have to it this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing this requires some string manipulations, that are not necessarily standard across SQL dialects.  You need to do the join between the child and the parent, in such a way that the child has exactly one "." after the parent code.

Here is an example is standard-ish SQL:

```
select child.id, parent.id, child.code, child.description
from t child join
     t parent
     on child.code like concat(parent.code, '.%') and
        child.code not like concat(parent.code, '.%.%');
```

EDIT:

To get the first row, use a `left outer join`:

```
select child.id, parent.id, child.code, child.description
from t child left outer join
     t parent
     on child.code like concat(parent.code, '.%') and
        child.code not like concat(parent.code, '.%.%');
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon. It works but one small problem. It doesnt the first row which ID = 1 and CODE= 'A' because it doesnt have a parent. I want it to be displayed and its parent ID should be 0 since top level doesnt have a parent